# How to solve Icon background distorted

Tags: css, web, icons

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOedt.png) the icon bg looks fine on single line sentence, but when the sentence too long or stack down, the icon is distorted, any way to solve it?

Below is the relative css:

```
.advantages-list li::before {
    content: '\f00c';
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: var(--global--color-primary);
    color: var(--global--color-white);
    margin-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please share HTML and more CSS as well then I can try to solve your issue.

Comment: I agree with WLI Frontend Team. Please, provide all html and css for the advantages-list structure. My best guess from what I see is that you should replace "width: 20px;" with "flex: 0 0 20px;". But without additional information, I cannot be sure.

Comment: Try adding `min-width:20px;` to your CSS to force the icon to at least be that width when in a flexbox environment